# How to join a model in solr with rails sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I need to join another model (GeoNameAlternateName) and tried it according to the doc. But for some reason I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown field option :prefix provided for field :name
```

My GeoNameCityModel is searchable like this:

```
searchable do
text :name
string :feature_class
string :feature_code
latlon(:lonlat) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(lat, lon) }
join(:name, :prefix => "alternate", :target => GeoNameAlternateName, :type => :text, :join => { :from => :geonames_id, :to => :geonames_id })
end
```

Both models have a field column? Does this maybe interfere?

I am running on mac osx, rails 4.1.8, 
ruby-2.1.1/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr
solr-spec
4.2.0.2013.03.06.22.32.13
solr-impl
4.2.0 1453694 - rmuir - 2013-03-06 22:32:13
lucene-spec
4.2.0
lucene-impl
4.2.0 1453694 - rmuir - 2013-03-06 22:25:29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running.
First of all I had to use the latest version from the git repo

```
  gem 'sunspot_rails'  , :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git'
  gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git' # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
```

then in the model:

```
join(:alternate_name,  :target => GeoNameAlternateName, :type => :text, :join => { :from => :geonames_id, :to => :geonames_id })
```

in the join model GeoNameAlternateName

```
 searchable do
    integer :geonames_id
    text :alternate_name
  end
```

Comment: could you please review my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262259/how-to-get-the-relational-records-using-rails-solr-search - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "prefix" is not in sunspot [2.1.1](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/v2.1.1), it was added afterwards. If you want to use it, then switch to the [master](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/master) branch

In your case it should be something like:

```
Sunspot.setup(GeoNameAlternateName) do
 integer :id
 ... all other fields 
end

Sunspot.setup(GeoNameCityModel) do
 integer :id
 integer :geoname_id
 join(:name, :type => :text, :join_string => 'from=geoname_id to=id')
 ... all other fields 
end
```

Comment: But how is the GeoNameAlternateName table referenced here?

Comment: And it does not work, it does not consider any results from the GeoNameAlternateName table

Comment: Solr is not a relational datababase. In Solr, both GeoNameAlternateName and GeoNameCityModel will end up in the same collection. So you'll have to add the "foreign key" to your GeoNameCityModel. And both of your models should have the id field. [Here](GeoNameCityModel) is an example in sunspot source code, and [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) is the Solr documentation on joins.

Comment: sorry, don't know how to edit the comment. This is the missing [link](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/v2.1.1/sunspot/spec/mocks/photo.rb) from the previous comment.

Comment: no it does not work at all. I tried to setup too simple models as the link demonstrates but i dont get matches